# C# Limit Calls Per Second

Tags: c#

I am calling a service that only allows 10 calls per second.  I am using Stopwatch and Thread.Sleep to limit my calls.  Are these the correct tools for this job, or should I be using Timers or some other tool.

```
     public void SomeFunction() {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        int numCallsThisSecond = 0;

        foreach(MyEvent changedEvent in changedEvents) {
            stopwatch.Start();

            service.ChangeEvent(changedEvent);

            numCallsThisSecond += 1;
            stopwatch.Stop();
            if(numCallsThisSecond==10 && stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds<=1000)
                Thread.Sleep((int)(1100-stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
            if(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds>1000) {
                stopwatch.Reset();
                numCallsThisSecond = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: The tools you are using should be fine. Is there anything wrong with what you have so far? Unless you different needs, the question here is primarily opinion based.

Comment: If everything is working, why not post to Code Review?

Comment: Thanks, I will try Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

As you already know it can be 10 calls / sec.  Code can be simple as follows :

```
    public void SomeFunction() 
    {
        foreach(MyEvent changedEvent in changedEvents) 
        {
            service.ChangeEvent(changedEvent);
            Thread.Sleep(100);//you already know it can be only 10 calls / sec
        }
    }
```

Edit : 
Ok got it, please see if following alternative will be helpful, it only allows 10 or less calls per second depending on how its performing :

```
    public void SomeFunction() 
    {
        DateTime lastRunTime = DateTime.MinValue;

        foreach(MyEvent changedEvent in changedEvents) 
        {
            lastRunTime = DateTime.Now;
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++)
            {
                if (lastRunTime.Second == DateTime.Now.Second)
                {
                    service.ChangeEvent(changedEvent);
                }
                else
                {
                    break;//it took longer than 1 sec for 10 calls, so break for next second
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had this initially.  But I didn't want to introduce inefficiency on any longer running calls that didn't run into the 10 per sec limit.

Comment: The `Stopwatch` is a better solution.  Even still you should use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now` for inward facing timings.  And the `Second` property returns the whole number of the second so if you began timings at 0.9 second, it returns 0 which is not really what one wants in this case.  Use `Stopwatch`; its the right tool for the job.